# c - can't understand why I have these errors: Invalid read of size 1 and Syscall param unlink(pathname) points to unaddressable byte(s)

Tags: c, server, client, system-calls, unlink

I'm doing an exercise, in which among other things, I have to read the configuration info from a txt file, and use them to set up a server. My code seems to work, the server starts correctly and the various buffers contain the information taken from the file, but starting my program with valgrind returns these errors, I can not understand what I'm wrong.

this is the main

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <config.h>

char* UNIXPATH1=NULL;

void cleanup(){
    if(UNIXPATH1!=NULL)
        unlink(UNIXPATH1);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fileconf=fopen("./try/in.txt","r");
    if(fileconf==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "File error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    set_conf(fileconf);
    UNIXPATH1=malloc(strlen(returnUnixpath())*sizeof(char));
    strncpy(UNIXPATH1,returnUnixpath(),strlen(returnUnixpath()));

    cleanup();
    atexit(cleanup);

    FILE *fileout=fopen(UNIXPATH1,"w");
    if(fileout==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "File error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fputs("hello",fileout);
    fclose(fileout);
    free(UNIXPATH1);

    return 0;
}
```

this is config.h

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MEM_ALL(r,c,msg) \
    if(!(r=c)) {perror(msg); fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Out of memory\n"); exit(errno); } 

typedef int make_iso_compilers_happy;


char* UNIXPATH;


char* returnUnixpath(){
    return UNIXPATH;
}

void set_conf(FILE *file){
    char buffer[4096];
    char* token1;
    char* saveptr1;
    char *array[3];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        MEM_ALL(array[i],malloc(1*sizeof(char)),"malloc array[i]");
    }
    i=0;
    char* tmp=malloc(sizeof(char));
    while(fgets(buffer,4096,file)!=NULL){ 
        if(buffer[0]!='#' && buffer[0]!='\n' && buffer[0]!=' '){
            buffer[strlen(buffer)-1]='\0';
            token1=strtok_r(buffer," ",&saveptr1);
            printf("s: %ld",strlen(token1));
            tmp=realloc(tmp,(strlen(token1))*sizeof(char));
            strncpy(tmp,token1,(strlen(token1)));

            for(i=0;i<3;i++){
                MEM_ALL(array[i],realloc(array[i],(strlen(token1)+1)*sizeof(char)),"realloc array[i]");
                strncpy(array[i],token1,(strlen(token1)+1));
                array[i][strlen(token1)]='\0';  
                if(i!=2)
                    token1=strtok_r(NULL," ",&saveptr1);
            }
            if(strncmp("UnixPath",tmp,8)==0){
                MEM_ALL(UNIXPATH,malloc(strlen(array[2])*sizeof(char)),"malloc unixpath");
                strncpy(UNIXPATH,array[2],strlen(array[2]));

            }
        }

    }
    free(tmp);
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        free(array[i]);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

this is the in.txt file

```
UnixPath         = ./try/o.txt
```

and this is valgrind output

```
==5897== Invalid read of size 1
==5897==    at 0x4C32D04: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x10905C: main (main.c:26)
==5897==  Address 0x522e9bb is 0 bytes after a block of size 11 alloc'd
==5897==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x108EB7: set_conf (config.h:44)
==5897==    by 0x10904A: main (main.c:25)
==5897== 
==5897== Invalid read of size 1
==5897==    at 0x4C32D04: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x10907D: main (main.c:27)
==5897==  Address 0x522e9bb is 0 bytes after a block of size 11 alloc'd
==5897==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x108EB7: set_conf (config.h:44)
==5897==    by 0x10904A: main (main.c:25)
==5897== 
==5897== Syscall param unlink(pathname) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==5897==    at 0x4F4DD47: unlink (syscall-template.S:78)
==5897==    by 0x108FE3: cleanup (main.c:14)
==5897==    by 0x1090AC: main (main.c:29)
==5897==  Address 0x522ea0b is 0 bytes after a block of size 11 alloc'd
==5897==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x109064: main (main.c:26)
==5897== 
==5897== Syscall param openat(filename) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==5897==    at 0x4F4BC8E: open (open64.c:47)
==5897==    by 0x4EC8589: _IO_file_open (fileops.c:189)
==5897==    by 0x4EC8589: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:281)
==5897==    by 0x4EBAEA9: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:78)
==5897==    by 0x4EBAEA9: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==5897==    by 0x1090CE: main (main.c:32)
==5897==  Address 0x522ea0b is 0 bytes after a block of size 11 alloc'd
==5897==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x109064: main (main.c:26)
==5897== 
==5897== Syscall param unlink(pathname) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==5897==    at 0x4F4DD47: unlink (syscall-template.S:78)
==5897==    by 0x108FE3: cleanup (main.c:14)
==5897==    by 0x4E7F040: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:108)
==5897==    by 0x4E7F139: exit (exit.c:139)
==5897==    by 0x4E5DB9D: (below main) (libc-start.c:344)
==5897==  Address 0x522ea00 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 11 free'd
==5897==    at 0x4C30D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x109138: main (main.c:40)
==5897==  Block was alloc'd at
==5897==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x109064: main (main.c:26)
==5897== 
s: 8==5897== 
==5897== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5897==     in use at exit: 11 bytes in 1 blocks
==5897==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 14 frees, 10,377 bytes allocated
==5897== 
==5897== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5897==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5897==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5897==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5897==    still reachable: 11 bytes in 1 blocks
==5897==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5897== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `returnUnixpath` function ?

Comment: "*`UNIXPATH1=malloc(strlen(returnUnixpath())*sizeof(char));`*" mind the `0`-terminator to make a `char`-array a C-"string".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all the forms using *strncpy* like

```
UNIXPATH1=malloc(strlen(returnUnixpath())*sizeof(char));
strncpy(UNIXPATH1,returnUnixpath(),strlen(returnUnixpath()));
```

by a use of *strdup*

```
UNIXPATH1=strdup(returnUnixpath());
```

as you can see this is very more practical and this also fix the problem of the final character missing in your case. Of course remove `array[i][strlen(token1)]='\0';` now useless.

Replace forms like :

```
tmp=realloc(tmp,(strlen(token1))*sizeof(char));
strncpy(tmp,token1,(strlen(token1)));
```

by

```
tmp=realloc(tmp, strlen(token1) + 1);
strcpy(tmp,token1);
```

Because of the `atexit(cleanup);` after `free(UNIXPATH1);` you need to do `UNIXPATH1 = NULL;` in *main* else *cleanup* access to the freed string at the end of *main* execution.

Other remarks :

- by definition `sizeof(char)` is 1
- it is strange to put code in a header file, if you cut code in several files use several source files
- when you `#include` one of your header use `"file.h"` rather than `<file.h>`

After the changes the execution under *valgrind* doesn't signal invalid accesses

Comment: thanks for the answer has solved my problems, I did not understand only one thing. Where should I put char * UNIXPATH1 = NULL? If I declare UNIXPATH1 = NULL within the main and not globally, the cleanup () function does not know what the UNIXPATH1 () variable is. While if the function is done: cleanup (char * UNIXPATH1) I have problems with the function atexit (cleanup) that returns warning at compile time:    passing argument 1 of 'atexit' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   atexit (cleanup);

Comment: @james if you call `free(UNIXPATH1);` at the end of the _main_ you need before the _return 0;_ to do `UNIXPATH1 = NULL;`, thank to that _cleanup_ called on _exit_ will not does the _unlink_ from a freed string. Your problem comes from the `exit(0);`,  you can add the explicit call of _cleanup();` before in `MEM_ALL ` allowing to not use atexit if you have problem with. Anyway `MEM_ALL` do not makes your code easy to read ...

Comment: if I do `UNIXPATH1=NULL;` before return 0; the file will not be deleted at the end of the program execution

Comment: @james I supposed you do not want to delete the file out of error. In that case move the `free(UNIXPATH1);` from _main_ into _cleanup_ just after the call to _unlink_ ... but why to create the file if it is always removed ?

Comment: because that's what the exercise asks but at this point I will avoid doing atexit (cleanup). However I edited the original question because I have another invalid read error

Comment: @james remove your edit and open a new question and in it give the new code, currently we still see the initial code, it is not possible to help you from it. Dont forget to mark the current question resolved